# Moving files to destination for a given date in windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to move few files from source location for a given date which will be recognized by a parameter passed to the batch.
whenever I am going to execute the script I am getting the below error.

```
D:\Adaptiv_Calib_Movement.bat XXXX 20170201
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

I am pretty sure move command is throwing this error but unable to fix it.Can anybody assist me to resolve it? Code snippet is attached herewith.

```
set inDate=%2%
set year=%inDate:~0,4%
set month=%inDate:~4,2%
set day=%inDate:~6,2%

cd /D D:/Adaptiv/EndOfDay

:: switch on the input parameter
IF "%1"=="XXXX" GOTO XXXX


:INVALIDPARAM
ECHO Invalid Parameter: Script was called with an invalid parameter >> "%log%"
exit 1

:NOPARAM
ECHO Invalid Parameter(s): Script was called with 0 or 1 parameters (2 required - Action and Reference Date) >> "%log%"
exit 1

:XXXX
ECHO Initiating %1 files movement  >> "%log%"

ECHO !year!-!month!-!day! >> "%log%"

::Move each trade file from the Source Folder to the Destination Folder

move "%SourceFolder%\CVA_Calib_!year!-!month!-!day!*dat" %DestinationFolder%
move "%SourceFolder%\CVA_Calib_!year!-!month!-!day!*txt" %DestinationFolder%
move "%SourceFolder%\PFE_CALIB_DAT_!year!-!month!-!day!*dat" %DestinationFolder%
move "%SourceFolder%\PFE_CALIB_DAT_!year!-!month!-!day!*txt" %DestinationFolder%
```

Comment: If you're pretty sure where the error lies, and that section of the code holds two variables whose values we have not been made aware of, do you think that your part code holds sufficient information for us to make a proper assessment?

Comment: Souvik Halder, based upon your latest comment your `%DestinationFolder%` variable value contains one or more spaces and should be doublequoted in your `move` commands! I will also note that your `set indate=%2%` should read `Set "indate=%~2"` and that your other variables should be set also using the same syntax, `Set "var=value"` as standard practice. For safety you should also surround any string using the variable `%SourceFolder%` with doublequotes too! As an additional note, you appear to be using a `%log%` variable which also hasn't been defined anywhere within the code snippets provided.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to throw a stone in the dark here and hope to hit a cat. I will see if I can resolve your issue in this answer, without testing anything.

I do not see where you set `%SourceFolder%` or `%DestinationFolder%, you use`!`in expansion and not`%`and I do not see that you have`setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` making me think you did not copy the entire script.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set inDate=%2%
set year=%inDate:~0,4%
set month=%inDate:~4,2%
set day=%inDate:~6,2%

set "SourceFolder=D:\Adaptiv\EndofDay"
set "DestinationFolder=D:\Some\Destination\Folder\"

cd /D %SourceFolder%

:: switch on the input parameter
IF "%1"=="XXXX" GOTO XXXX

:INVALIDPARAM
ECHO Invalid Parameter: Script was called with an invalid parameter >> "%log%"
exit 1

:NOPARAM
ECHO Invalid Parameter(s): Script was called with 0 or 1 parameters
Echo Usage: Command Action Reference_Date >> "%log%"
exit 1

:XXXX
ECHO Initiating %1 files movement  >> "%log%"
ECHO !year!-!month!-!day! >> "%log%"

::Move each trade file from the Source Folder to the Destination Folder

move "%SourceFolder%\CVA_Calib_!year!-!month!-!day!*dat" %DestinationFolder%
move "%SourceFolder%\CVA_Calib_!year!-!month!-!day!*txt" %DestinationFolder%
move "%SourceFolder%\PFE_CALIB_DAT_!year!-!month!-!day!*dat" %DestinationFolder%
move "%SourceFolder%\PFE_CALIB_DAT_!year!-!month!-!day!*txt" %DestinationFolder%
endlocal
```

Comment: Yes. thats right. I didnt copy the complete script over here. those parameters I have defined at the initial stage.

SET SourceFolder=\\wapprib00001q80\d$\Program Files\Sungard\Adaptiv\PeriodicTemplates\Latest CALIB Files
SET DestinationFolder=\\wapprib00001q80\d$\Program Files\Sungard\Adaptiv\PeriodicTemplates

:: if no input parameter is specified, display the "Invalid Parameter" error
IF [%1]==[] GOTO NOPARAM
IF [%2]==[] GOTO NOPARAM
ECHO First Parameter passed to script is: %1 >> "%log%"
ECHO Second Parameter passed to script is: %2 >> "%log%"